# Run an executable in WSL from a Visual Studio launch profile

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio in Windows I can create a launchSettings.json profile which starts up an executable I specify and then attaches to it. Is it possible to do the same with an executable in WSL?

I'm writing an extension to a Linux program. The extension is a .Net 6 class library, so in order to debug it I need to start up the Linux program and then immediately attach. I could start up the program manually and then attach to the process from Visual Studio, but the extension loads first thing and I can't hop over to Visual Studio and attach fast enough to catch it.

I've found [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022) for debugging .Net ASP and console apps in WSL from Visual Studio, but those instructions always assume that the project I'm debugging is itself executable.

Answer (score 0):

The section [WSL settings in the launch profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2#wsl-settings-in-the-launch-profile) details the options for the launch profile. You can use `executablePath` and `commandLineArgs` to change what VS launches for debugging.

Comment: ah cool, that looks promising. When I try that though, I get an error popup: "The project doesn't know how to run the profile with name '...' and command 'WSL'." The json schema also flags my commandName of "WSL".